# Interrupt and restart a transition in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my bl.ock: https://bl.ocks.org/JulienAssouline/94dfdd391b16b47cff862a4708515dc6

If you click on PE and then on SUMMERSIDE a transition will happen. If you don't wait for that transition to finish and click on CHARLOTTETOWN the other lines will be removed but the `.on("end")` part of the transition still proceeds resulting in the text I am appending on end to appear again in the next transition.

I am `console.log(this)` in the `.on("end")` function so you can see what is going on.

What I am wondering is, is it possible to interrupt a transition, and then restart it?

I can interrupt the transition by doing:

`if(counter == 0){
        d3.selectAll("path").interrupt()
      }`

at the start of the .each loop. But then I can't figure out a way to restart it.

Is there also a better approach to solving this problem if this isn't possible?

Here is the crux of the transition code

```
var counter = 0;


lines_transition.each(function(path, index){



var line_transitions = d3.select(this)
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d.values[0].Annual
      })
      .transition()
      .delay(index * 300)
      .duration(320)
      .style("opacity",1)
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
      .style("opacity", 0.3)



     line_transitions.on("end", function(d, i){

      console.log(counter)

    console.log(this)

    if (first == true) {
     nextBiggest = d.values[0].Annual
     first = false
    }


    if (nextBiggest < d.values[0].Annual) {
      nextBiggest = d.values[0].Annual
      if (nextBiggest == d.values[0].Annual) {

       d3.select(this).style("stroke", "red").style("opacity", 1).style("stroke-width", "2px").style("stroke-dasharray", "2,2").raise()


         var line_color= this.style.stroke

          d3.selectAll(".new_record").remove()

        var record_text = g.append("text")
         .attr("x", width + 5)
         .attr("y", yScale(d.values[d.values.length-1].Temperature))
         .text(d.values[d.values.length-1].Year + " new record")
         .attr("class", "new_record")
         .attr("id", d.values[d.values.length-1].Year)

      }
    }

    var birthyear = document.getElementById("birthyear").value

    if (d.key == birthyear) {
      d3.select(this).style("stroke", "red").style("opacity", 1).style("stroke-width", "2px").style("stroke-dasharray", "2,2")

      g.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 5)
      .attr("y", yScale(d.values[d.values.length-1].Temperature))
      .text(d.values[d.values.length-1].Year)
    }




     if (d.key == "2017") {
      d3.select(this).style("stroke", "red").style("opacity", 1).style("stroke-width", "2px")

      g.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 5)
      .attr("y", yScale(d.values[d.values.length-1].Temperature))
      .text(d.values[d.values.length-1].Year)
     }

               counter += 1


  }) // on end




  g.append("text")
  .transition()
  .delay(index * 300)
  .duration(320)
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .text(this.className.animVal)
    .attr("class", "year_label")
    .transition()
  .duration(0.1)
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .on("end", function(){
     if (this.textContent == 2017) {
        d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1)
     }

  })

    }) // linetransition
```

Comment: how many birth year fields do you need?

Comment: @rioV8 ah you can ignore the birthyear part. It's not that important to me. The big bugaboo is the `record_text` and the "2017" text which is being appended again after you switch cities before the animation ends because the animation doesn't stop.